# SSIS Package error--Column data type DT_R8 is not supported by the PipelineBuffer class

Tags: ssis

"Column data type DT_R8 is not supported by the PipelineBuffer class."

This log was happening when im running the whole container.
on script component sebugging is working finely, single task also working finely. but while im running whole package im getting this error. advance thanks to helpers :)

Comment: Did you get a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue today. While my situation seem to be slightly different, the solution may still be applicable. Let me describe my situation first.

I have a rather complex package which has been in use for a long time. It stopped working after I made some changes to it today. The package still worked from inside the Visual Studio (2017), but gave a few different types of errors when run on the server as an agent job. The errors were:

1. Column data type DT_R8 is not supported by PipelineBuffer class.
2. System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Solution, which worked on two of my packages, was to *recreate* the Script Component. By recreating, I mean that create a brand new Script Component, as opposed to simply copy-and-paste the entire old Script Component. Then, manually transfer the code starting from "public class ScriptMain : UserComponent" and all the way to the end.